# Php Ajax form submit in colorbox

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submit, colorbox

I have a form  with some php to validate and insert in the database on submit and the form opens in colorbox.

So far so good. What I'm trying to do is to close colorbox and refresh a div on success.

I guess I need to pass a response to ajax from php if everything OK, close the colorbox with something like setTimeout($.fn.colorbox.close,1000); and refresh the div, but I'm stuck because I'm new in ajax.

I'll appreciate any help here.

Here is my ajax:

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('.cbox-form').colorbox({maxWidth: '75%', onComplete: function(){
   cbox_submit();

  }});
});


function cbox_submit()
{
  jQuery("#pre-process").submit(function(){
   jQuery.post(
      jQuery(this).attr('action'),
      jQuery(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
       jQuery().colorbox({html: data, onComplete: function(){
          cbox_submit();

        }});
      }
    );
    return false;
  });
}
```

form php code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(-1); 
include "conf/config.php";

if(isset($_REQUEST['rid'])){$rid=safe($_REQUEST['rid']);}
if(isset($_REQUEST['pid'])){$pid=safe($_REQUEST['pid']);}
$msg = '';
if (!$_SESSION['rest_id']) $_SESSION['rest_id']=$rid; //change to redirect

$session_id=session_id();


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['opta'])){
$opta=safe($_POST['opta']);
$extraso = implode(',',array_values( array_filter($_POST['opta']) ));
                    }

if (array_search("", $_POST['opt']) !== false) 
{
$msg = "Please select all accessories!";
}else{

$extrasm = implode(',',array_values( array_filter($_POST['opt']) ));

if ($_POST['opt'] && isset($_POST['opta'])) {$extras= $extrasm .",". $extraso;}
if ($_POST['opt'] && !isset($_POST['opta'])) {$extras= $extrasm;}
if (!$_POST['opt'] && isset($_POST['opta'])) {$extras= $extraso;}

$sql['session_id']  = $session_id;
    $sql['rest_id'] = $_POST['rid'];
    $sql['prod_id'] = $_POST['pid'];
    $sql['extras']  = $extras;
    $sql['added_date']  = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $newId=insert_sql("cart",$sql);

    }
}
?>

<form id="pre-process" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<div style="background-color:#FFF; padding:20px;">
<?=$msg;?>
  <?php
  $name = getSqlField("SELECT name FROM products WHERE resid=".$_SESSION['rest_id']." and id=".$pid."","name");
  echo "<div style='color:#fff; background-color:#F00;padding:10px;' align='center'><h2>".$name."</h2></div><div style='background-color:#FFF; padding: 20px 70px 30px 70px; '>Please select accessories.<br><br>";
 $getRss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optional_groups_product where prodid=".$pid." order by id asc");
    while ($rsrw = @mysql_fetch_array($getRss)) {

  $goptionals = getSqlField("SELECT goptionals FROM optionals_groups WHERE resid=".$_SESSION['rest_id']." and id=".$rsrw['goptid']."","goptionals");

        $goptionals=explode(', ',($goptionals));

echo "<select name='opt[]' id='opt[]' style='width:220px;'>";
echo "<option value='' >Select Options</option>";
    foreach($goptionals as $v)
    {
         $vname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optionals where id=".$v." LIMIT 0,1");
         while ($rsgb = @mysql_fetch_array($vname)) {
             $aa=$rsgb['optional'];
         }
             echo "<option value=".$v." >".$aa."</option>";


    }
         echo "</select>(required)<br>";       
    //}
        }
        $getRss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optional_product where prodid=".$pid.""); 
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
       <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#EAFFEC">
<div style="width:440px; "> 
<?php

while ($rssp = @mysql_fetch_array($getRss)) {
 $optional=getSqlField("SELECT optional FROM optionals WHERE id=".$rssp['optid']."","optional");
 $price=getSqlField("SELECT price FROM optionals WHERE id=".$rssp['optid']."","price");
?>
<div style="width:180px;background-color:#EAFFEC; float:left;padding:10px;""><input type="checkbox" name="opta[]" id="opta[]" value="<?=$rssp['optid']?>"  /> <i><?=$optional?> [<?=CURRENCY?><?=$price?> ]</i> </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

</td>
 </tr></table>
<input type="hidden" name="rid" value="<?=$rid?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?=$pid?>"/>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="submit" /><input  id='submit' class="CSSButton"    style="width:120px; float:right;" name='submit' type='submit' value=' Continue ' /><br />

<br /><br />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page on submit you should [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). Can you show us your html ?

Comment: i don't see what the issue here. Its already in the docs. call `$.colorbox.close()` and it will fire `onClosed` function where you can update the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know colobox, but if I understand well what you are trying to do,
I would say your javascript should more look like this

```
function cbox_submit()
{
  jQuery("#pre-process").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form to reload the page
    jQuery.post(
      jQuery(this).attr('action')
    , jQuery(this).serialize()
    , function(data) {
        if (data['ok']) { // ok variable received in json
          jQuery('#my_colorbox').colorbox.close(); // close the box
        }
      }
    );
    return false;
  });
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#my_colorbox').colorbox({
    maxWidth: '75%'
  , onComplete: cbox_submit // Bind the submit event when colorbox is loaded
  });
});
```

You should separate at least your php script that does the post part.

And this php (called with `jQuery(this).attr('action')`) should return a json `ok` variable if successfull. Example:

```
<?php
# ... post part ...
# if success
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('ok' => true));
?>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense so I'll try and post an update. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why buy I'm getting {"ok":true} printed on top of the colorbox and nothing happen. looks like the function cbox_submit() is not receiving the data. any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you ARE receiving the data (`{'ok': true}` is the json you sent back) but colorbox seems to display the data instead of just self close. You have to check the response with firebug and the headers received.

Comment: There was an error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started.... everything is working now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you still have this warning ? (you have it because the you are already defining the headers sooner in your code, you have to remove them, otherwise your json can be wrongly interpreted)